# Slide presentation software which allows real-time text writing.

Tags: presentation, slideshow, real-time

What slide presentation software (preferably compatible with .ppx) allows the user to write text over the presentation in real-time?

I have a powerpoint presentation which I usually share over skype's screen share. However, sometimes I need to write text over the slides during the very presentation, but powerpoint does not allow me to do it. Before, I used an education platform called Wiziq, but that is not possible anymore.

Thanks to you all in advance.

Comment: Purely software?  There are a few products that require dedicated hardware.  Probably not useful if you are doing remote screen sharing.

Comment: Indeed. But what I need is very simple. It's a Powerpoint which would allow me write over the slides (at full-screen mode) during the very presentation.